# qgis2web install problem

Tags: qgis2web

Using QGIS 2.14.2 after installing qgis2web, the app doesn't appear in the plugin tab, even though all the files were successfully downloaded and verified in the python plugin directory. Other plugins I downloaded have installed just fine. Tried uninstall and install again, tried reinstalling, tried quitting and restarting qgis, still no app.

Comment: I think its in the web tab